# Prolog function removeSecond which removes the second element of a given list. For example:

Tags: prolog

```
removeSecond([H|[X|T]], L) :- L = [H|T].
```

this is my code but I can not get it to return this results needed

For example:

```
removeSecond ([A [A B] C], L)
Returns L = [A C] and
removeSecond ([A B [C D]], L)
Returns L = [A [C D]]
```

Comment: What do you mean with `[A [A B] C]`? Do you mean `[A, [A, B], C]`? Or `[A | [A | B] | C]`? And, exactly, what do you expect and what do you obtain?

Comment: m just trying to remove the second element of a list. evertime I put it in prolog i get this error amzi_listener:listen$((removeSecond ( NEAR HERE [A [A B] C], L)))

Comment: Elements of a list in Prolog should be separated by commas. But the example results you show (if commas are used) look correct. The second element of list `[A, [A,B], C]` is `[A,B]`. Removing the second element results in `[A, C]` which is what you got. Similarly, the second element of list `[A, B, [C,D]]` is `B`. Removing it results in `[A, [C,D]]`.  If these aren't the results you expected, then please explain what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where, exacly, is you problem but...

what about writing `removeSecond/2` as follows?

```
removeSecond([H1, _ | T], [H1 | T]).
```

Comment: im just trying to remove the second element of a list. evertime I put it in prolog i get this error amzi_listener:listen$((removeSecond ( **NEAR HERE** [A [A B] C], L))) .

Comment: What about empty lists? And those with a single element?